# Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays

Tags: solidity, arrays, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to update an old code base  to  `^0.8.1;`. The coded declares a player array and after operations being done, deletes it in order to make contract free for new players:

```
pragma solidity >0.4.99;
address[] public players;
// do stuff here...
// empty players array
players.length = 0;
```

However I get this error:

> Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.

So I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to empty the array in `0.8.x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code-word `delete` that sets a variable to its initial value which is all 0's for an array.

`delete players;`

[You can read on the `delete` command in the Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#delete)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeIndex(uint256 index) external
{   
    require(index < temp.length);

    for(uint256 i = index ; i < temp.length - 1; i ++)
    {
        temp[i] = temp[i + 1];
    }

    temp.pop();
}
```

Use this piece of code if you want to resize the array and preserve the order of the elements. It is not gas-wise, but for smaller arrays works.